# "Transaction not found" when Capturing payment transaction with Bambora

Tags: javascript, node.js, payment-gateway, ecmascript-2016, bambora

I'm implementing the [Inline Checkout](https://developer.bambora.com/europe/checkout/web-sdk/inlinecheckout-reference) from Bambora. The authorization step works without any problem. But when it comes to capturing the payment I always get the error `Transaction not found`.

This is what I do:

```
const options = {
    headers: { Authorization: `Basic ${ apiKey }` },
};
const { payload } = {
    amount
};
const { data } = await axios.post(`https://transaction-v1.api-eu.bambora.com/transactions/${ txnid }/capture`, payload, options);
```

I also tried making the request with included `transactionoperations`:

```
const options = {
    headers: { Authorization: `Basic ${ apiKey }` },
};
const { payload } = {
    amount,
    transactionoperations: [{ id: txnid }],
};
const { data } = await axios.post(`https://transaction-v1.api-eu.bambora.com/transactions/${ txnid }/capture`, payload, options);
```

I get the same error when trying to get transaction information:

```
const options = {
    headers: { Authorization: `Basic ${ apiKey }` },
};
const { data } = await axios.get(`https://merchant-v1.api-eu.bambora.com/transactions/${ txnid }`, options);
```

As I understand [the documentation](https://developer.bambora.com/europe/checkout/handling-payments/handling-with-api) I'm doing everything right, but I can't get it to work.

After looking at [Bamboras own implementation](https://github.com/bambora/checkout-opencart/blob/master/upload/admin/model/extension/payment/bambora_online_checkout.php) in PHP I can't see any issues with my code.

After looking at the Report Dashboard for a specific order in the URL doesn't match the ID I have saved in the database. The value of `txnid` returned on the Inline Checkout [Authorize event](https://developer.bambora.com/europe/checkout/web-sdk/advanced-usage#eventauthorize) doesn't seem to be accurate.

Comment: What if you put the Authorization header key in quotes?

Comment: @Evelijn the auth works for other requests. It looks like it's a bug at Bambora and nothing wrong with my code.

Comment: Could you paste your event handler in the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was way off of where the problem was in our code. With help from the Bambora support and @Evelijn nudging in the right direction the problem is solved.

When sending the `txnid` from the client to the server the validation ensured that the value only contained digits. What I had missed was that it also changed it to a Number type.

The `txnid` is a String of 18 digits, javascript can handle numbers that are at most 17 digits big. When `txnid` was changed to a Number the last digit would be rounded to 0.

So `123456789012345678` would become `123456789012345680`.

When I changed the validation not to cast `txnid` to a Number everything works.